# How to convert PostgreSQL time without time zone to date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, time, date-conversion

I have a REST API endpoint that's using PostgreSQL that I'm querying against  and one of the fields is a `time without time zone`. The endpoint returns the field as a human readable string like so `20:33:32.221397`.

I'd like to convert this on the front-end to another string like `October 10, 2018 23:16` using JavaScript but the `Date()` object does not support this format.

I tried moment.js and it throws an exception saying the format doesn't comply with RFC format.

If it comes down to it, I'd like to just use regular expressions and extract the parts, convert it to milliseconds then use the `Date()` object but I'm not sure how to account for the floating point part as I'm sure it's of great significance.

Even the 7 parameter `new Date()` constructor expects the 2nd argument to be a month index, which I do not know.

So, a JS library will do or I'd like to know the math on how to convert those parts into a timestamp. The rest is trivial. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no straight way to parse more than 3 digits for SSS in time. For your reference, there was an issue open with moment [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3256)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
function convertTime(apiTime) {
  var chunked = apiTime.split(":");

  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(chunked[0]);
  date.setMinutes(chunked[1]);

  return moment(date).format('MMMM DD, YYYY H:mm');
}

convertTime("20:33:32.221397") // October 10, 2018 20:33
```

Here is a sandbox: https://jsfiddle.net/hxmrs92q/3/

Comment: Your answer actually helped me in figuring out that the `TIME` type cannot represent both time and date so it did kind of answer my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I was a fool. I realized the `TIME` type does not carry date fields with it. The PHP function that was formatting the time simply assumed the date part. I have since changed my type to  `TIMESTAMP` now.